# Handle Response Kotlin Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm new to Kotlin and android development. Have been struggling to get my retrofit api to work.
But have found a way to do it after some search on SO. I get the data response now, but I don't know how to "separate" it, so that i can work around with it.

this is my json response:

```
"data": [
    {
        "alpha2Code": "PT",
        "name": "Portugal",
        "prefixCode": null,
        "id": "9ba94c99-7362-47c2-f31f-08d87a662921",
        "active": true,
        "created": "2020-10-27T10:50:46.895831"
    }
```

and my model class

```
data class Country (
    @SerializedName("alpha2Code")
    val alpha2Code: String?,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String?,
    @SerializedName("active")
    val active: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("created")
    val created: String?
): Serializable


class Countrys {
    var countrys: List<Country> = emptyList()
}
```

and finally my get data function

```
fun getDataCountry() {
    val call: Call<Countrys> = ApiClient.getClient.getCountries()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Countrys> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Countrys>?, response: Response<Countrys>?) {
            // val carResponse = response.body()
            val body = response?.body()
            Log.e("dadosApi2","retorno response: " + body)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Countrys>?, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("dadosApiError","erro no retorno " + t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

I get the response, but I don't know how to unfold the data, so that I can for example add all country names to an `ArrayList`.

I have tried doing this without the class Countrys, using <List> or Arraylist but i get the error on my response:

E/dadosApiError: erro no retorno Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

```
fun getDataCountry() {
    val call: Call<ArrayList<Country>> = ApiClient.getClient.getCountries()
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Country>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Country>>?, response: Response<ArrayList<Country>>?) {
            // val carResponse = response.body()
            val body = response?.body()

            Log.e("dadosApi2","retorno response: " + body)

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Country>>?, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("dadosApiError","erro no retorno " + t.message)
        }

    })
}
```

I have also tried previously with List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to change `Countrys` class into a `data class` and add the `SerializedName` `data` for the object `countrys` like this

```
data class Countrys(@SerializedName("data")var countrys: List<Country>)
```

then you can access your data by using this

```
var countryNames = mutableListOf<String>()
for (country in response?.body().countrys){
  countryNames.add(country.name)
}
```

Comment: Well thats what i have before, and i always got an error handling my response, then i saw some answers on SO that i have to change it to the way i have now due to the json output i have.

Comment: E/dadosApiError: erro no retorno Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: it's just a difference in the object type, if List is not working for you, then try an ArrayList

Comment: you should also edit your question to include the error and mention the line where it happens at.

Comment: i missed this btw, if you are doing response?.body() it will not work, since you are still using Countrys, you will have to use this now to access the data response?.body().countrys

Comment: I'm trying those suggestions , but still have not fixed my problem. Continue getting the same error when i stop using Countrys class

Comment: update your question with the current code and the error so i can help you correctly

Comment: when you said to alter to response?.body().countrys, i cant access that.

Comment: set Countrys to be a data class as well like this
data class Countrys (var countrys: List<Country>) and try again

Comment: after that , now the response is null

Comment: did u add the serialized name for countrys? which is "data"

Comment: ya , you are right, thanks for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: i will update my answer and if this solved your problem i think you should mark it for others to help them in the future